# For loop overwrites value when appending to list in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I am trying to create a nested dictionary out of a list of postcodes and locations. Somehow I keep overwriting the value in the loop leaving only the last value on the list.

Code snippet

```
postcode_dict = {}
postcode_list = [['01000', 'location1', 'district1', 'state1'], 
                 ['01000', 'location2', 'district1', 'state1'], 
                 ['01200', 'location3', 'district2', 'state2'], 
                 ['01200', 'location4', 'district2', 'state2']]

for row in postcode_list:
    state = row[3]
    state_dict = {}
    if state not in state_dict:
        district_loc = []
        temp = [{row[1]: row[0]}]
        district_loc.append(temp)
    state_dict[row[2]] = district_loc
    postcode_dict[row[3]] = {district: district_loc}

print(postcode_dict)
```

Results:

```
{'state1': {'district1': [{'location2': '01000'}]}, 'state2': {'district2': [{'location4': '01200'}]}}
```

Expected Results:

```
{'state1': {'district1': [{'location1': '01000'}, {'location2': '01000'}]}, 'state2': {'district2': [{'location3': '01200'}, {'location4': '01200'}]}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because you are overwriting the value of `state_dict` in each iteration.

```py
postcode_dict = {}
for row in postcode_list:
    state = row[3]
    district = row[2]
    loc_postcode = {row[1]: row[0]}
    
    if state not in postcode_dict:
        postcode_dict[state] = {}
        
    if district not in postcode_dict[state]:
        postcode_dict[state][district] = []

    postcode_dict[state][district].append(loc_postcode)
   
print(postcode_dict)
```

---

```
{'state1': {'district1': [{'location1': '01000'}, {'location2': '01000'}]}, 'state2': {'district2': [{'location3': '01200'}, {'location4': '01200'}]}}
```

**Update:**
An alternative approach without using indices:

```py
postcode_dict = {}
for postcode, location, district, state in postcode_list:
    if state not in postcode_dict:
        postcode_dict[state] = {}
    if district not in postcode_dict[state]:
        postcode_dict[state][district] = []
    postcode_dict[state][district].append({location: postcode})
print(postcode_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
postcode_dict = {}
postcode_list = [['01000', 'location1', 'district1', 'state1'], 
                 ['01000', 'location2', 'district1', 'state1'], 
                 ['01200', 'location3', 'district2', 'state2'], 
                 ['01200', 'location4', 'district2', 'state2']]

for row in postcode_list:
    
    state = row[3]
    district = row[2]
    
    if state not in postcode_dict:
        postcode_dict[state] = {district: [{row[1]: row[0]}]}
    else:
        postcode_dict[state][district].append({row[1]: row[0]})
    

print(postcode_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variation that is using [`.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/stdtypes.html?#dict.setdefault):

```py
for code, location, district, state in postcode_list:
    state_dict = postcode_dict.setdefault(state, {})
    state_dict.setdefault(district, []).append({location: code})
```

Or, even simpler, just one pipe:

```py
for code, location, district, state in postcode_list:
    (postcode_dict.setdefault(state, {})
     .setdefault(district, []).append({location: code}))
```

Result for the sample:

```py
{'state1': {'district1': [{'location1': '01000'}, {'location2': '01000'}]},
 'state2': {'district2': [{'location3': '01200'}, {'location4': '01200'}]}}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are in each loop iteration either resetting `district_loc` to an empty array or you are assigning the same instance from the previous iteration.

So after the first **and** second iteration `district_loc` is `[{'location2': '01000'}]`.

This code sample produces your expected result:

```py
postcode_list = [['01000', 'location1', 'district1', 'state1'], 
                 ['01000', 'location2', 'district1', 'state1'], 
                 ['01200', 'location3', 'district2', 'state2'], 
                 ['01200', 'location4', 'district2', 'state2']]

state_dict = {}
for row in postcode_list:
    postcode = row[0]
    location = row[1]
    district = row[2]
    state = row[3]
    
    if state not in state_dict:
        state_dict[state] = {}
    if district not in state_dict[state]:
        state_dict[state][district] = []
    if location not in state_dict[state][district]:
        state_dict[state][district].append({location: postcode})

print(state_dict)
```